# Mi aplicación de consola no se ejecuta al usar tarea programada destinada a ello

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Creé una aplicación de consola por medio del visual studio (c#) para hacer el envío de emails en horarios distintos por día, todo por medio de un timer. Hasta aquí bien, la testeé y funciona correctamente. Lo que necesito ahora es poder ejecutar mi aplicación y que esté corriendo constantemente para que pueda hacer ese envío de emails de manera automática, para lo que creé una tarea programada en windows. Ahí está el problema: ejecuta la aplicación de forma correcta, pero al momento de hacer el envío de los mails no lo hace. No creo que el problema esté en mi código, ya que cuando depuro desde el visual funciona bien, pero cuando la tarea programada lo llama no, pero por las dudas a continuación posteo el código (tener en cuenta que los horarios son ficticios, a fin de poder testear el envío de los correos):

```
public class Program
{
    static System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer1.AutoReset = true;

        timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);

        timer1.Start();

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            EnviarMail.Correo mail = new EnviarMail.Correo();

            //Horas de envio
            var horaEnvio = "09:05:00";
            var horaEnvio2 = "09:06:00";
            var partesHoraEnvio = horaEnvio.Split(new char[1] { ':' });
            var partesHoraEnvio2 = horaEnvio2.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

            //Hora actual
            var fechaHoraActual = DateTime.Now;

            //Convierto el string de la hora actual en un integer
            var fechaHoraEnvio = new DateTime(fechaHoraActual.Year, fechaHoraActual.Month, fechaHoraActual.Day,
                       int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[0]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[1]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[2]));
            var fechaHoraEnvio2 = new DateTime(fechaHoraActual.Year, fechaHoraActual.Month, fechaHoraActual.Day,
                       int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio2[0]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio2[1]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio2[2]));

            //Declaro variable de tipo timespan
            TimeSpan ts;
            TimeSpan ts2;

            //Comparo: si la hora de envío es mayor a la actual
            if (fechaHoraEnvio > fechaHoraActual)
                //Mi variable de timespan equivale a la resta entre hora de envío y hora actual
                ts = fechaHoraEnvio - fechaHoraActual;
            else
            {
                //Añado a mi hora de envío 1 día
                fechaHoraEnvio = fechaHoraEnvio.AddDays(1);
                //Vuelvo a restar hora de envío y hora actual
                ts = fechaHoraEnvio - fechaHoraActual;
            }
            if (fechaHoraEnvio2 > fechaHoraActual)
                //Mi variable de timespan equivale a la resta entre hora de envío y hora actual
                ts2 = fechaHoraEnvio2 - fechaHoraActual;
            else
            {
                //Añado a mi hora de envío 1 día
                fechaHoraEnvio2 = fechaHoraEnvio2.AddDays(1);
                //Vuelvo a restar hora de envío y hora actual
                ts2 = fechaHoraEnvio2 - fechaHoraActual;
            }

            //Espero el tiempo de mi timespan y ejecuto el envío del correo.
            Task.Delay(ts).ContinueWith((x) => mail.enviarCorreo());
            Task.Delay(ts2).ContinueWith((x) => mail.enviarCorreo());

            timer1.Stop();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LogController.save(this, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

También quisiera volver mi aplicación transparente de cara al usuario, por lo que intenté ocultar la consola, pero esto solo resulta en el cierre de la aplicación. Creé un servicio de windows en reemplazo, pero al momento de instalarlo tampoco funciona. Por favor si alguien sabe cómo hacer esto de que sea transparente, sería de gran ayuda.

Por otra parte... justo en la última línea de comandos puse `//LogController.save(this, ex);` y está comentado ya que al ser un método estático no me toma el "this" pero tampoco sé cómo hacer referencia al objeto que debería pasarle... actualmente llama a la función "save" de la clase "LogController":

```
public static void save(object obj, Exception ex)
    {
        string filename = string.Format("LOG_{0:yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm.ss}.txt", DateTime.Now);
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\KGL\source\repos\Servicio\Logs\";
        string path = Path.Combine(filePath, filename);
        string hora = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);

        StackTrace stacktrace = new StackTrace();
        sw.WriteLine(obj.GetType().FullName + " " + hora);
        sw.WriteLine(stacktrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name + " - " + ex.Message);
        sw.WriteLine("");

        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();

        MailMessage correo = new MailMessage();
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient envio = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(); //Verifica si el correo y password ingresados son válidos

        //Limpio campos si ya escribí destinatarios anteriormente
        correo.To.Clear();
        correo.Body = "";
        correo.Subject = "";
        correo.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //Asigno valores
        correo.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@example.com"));
        correo.From = new MailAddress("email@example.com");
        correo.Subject = "Error";
        correo.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        correo.Body = "Mensaje automatico - favor de no responder";

        //Defino parámetros de cliente
        envio.Port = 25;
        envio.EnableSsl = true;
        envio.Host = "xxxxx";
        envio.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@example.com", "password");
        envio.Timeout = 10000;

        //Para adjuntar archivo
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path);
        correo.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        envio.Send(correo);
    }
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Instala tu aplicacion como un servicio, y no lo ejecutes como tarea, 
 https://dzone.com/articles/create-windows-services-in-c

Comment: Entonces que es lo que quieres, ocultar la consola o crear un servicio?

Comment: Te dejo tambien el [Tutorial oficial de Microsoft para crear una aplicación de servicio de Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que ya creé una aplicación de consola, sería la idea poder ocultarla. Pero si es más eficaz un servicio de windows, entonces crearé un servicio de windows. El punto es que corra en segundo plano de manera constante, lo cual no estoy pudiendo lograr de ninguna de las dos maneras.

Comment: Y procura separar las secciones de tu codigo en metodos, para mejor claridad y mantenimiento, elimina la parte de Timer1 no lo estas usando para el envio de tus correos.

Comment: @MarianellaCabreraAhumada Entonces lo mejor que puedes hacer es crearlo como un servicio de Windows, hay varias maneras de instalar el servicio, y para depurarlo primero debes instalarlo y despues probar, es diferente que con las aplicaciones de consola o winforms

Comment: si solo vas a enviar dos correos en horas especificas, creo que te la complicaste demasiado, solo podrias crear dos tareas a las horas especificas y listo, sin necesidad de estarlo corriendo todo el tiempo, solo se ejecuta a la hora que indicas en la tare.

Answer (score 2):

Hace tiempo tuve que hacer un `Windows Service` que enviaba `email` y era programable, cada 30min. Decidi hacerlo configurable y es algo parecido a lo que intentas hacer.

Me tome la libertad de adaptar un ejemplo simple creando una aplicación de Consola con un servicio de windows que envia emails cada tanto tiempo.

Da click [aqui](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QU3YFKT5WypdCAworJmyEcAFQ1ck1H-1) para descargar el cogido de ejemplo.

Te explico:

1. Crear un proyecto de consola.
2. Agregue `Log4Net`: es una librería gratuita que nos permite incluir en nuestra aplicación la funcionalidad de “logging” de una forma rápida y sencilla.

   Log4Net se agrega mediante **Nuget**
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que Log4Net funcione correctamente es necesario:

Agregar esta linea en `AssemblyInfo.cs`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//Log4Net
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = false)]
```

Agregar esta sección en `app.config`

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="./logs/ServicioDePrueba.log" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] %logger{1} - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Crear una instancia de `ILog`

```
//log para crear archivo de log y ver si algo esta fallando
        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Utilizar los metodos .Error, .Info, según sea necesario para generar el log.

```
Logger.Info("Programa iniciado: " + DateTime.Now);
Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
```

3. Agregar Servicio de Windows al proyecto:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez agregado el servicio hay que darle clic derecho en el archivo del servicio que esta en el explorador de soluciones y seleccionar la opción `ver código`.

El código del servicio quedo así:

```
using log4net;
using ServicioDePrueba.Helper;
using ServicioDePrueba.Infos;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ServicioDePrueba
{
    partial class ServicioDePrueba : ServiceBase
    {
        #region Declaraciones

        //Tomo esta valor del config y le digo cada cuantos minutos se va ejecutar
        private const string TimerMinKey = "Timer.Min";

        //Aqui toma los datos para el envio del email desde web.config
        private const string MailBodyKey = "Mail.Body";

        private const string MailSubjectKey = "Mail.Subject";
        private const string MailAuthUserKey = "Mail.Auth.User";

        //Si esta habilitado el modo pruebas mando correo al email configurado como para pruebas
        private const string SendTestModeKey = "Send.TestMode";

        private const string SendTestEmailsKey = "Send.TestEmails";
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer = null;

        //log para crear archivo de log y ver si algo esta fallando
        private readonly ILog _logger;// = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        #endregion Declaraciones

        public ServicioDePrueba(ILog logger)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _logger.Info("Servicio iniciado.");

            //Si no se configuraron los minutos pongo 5 por default
            var strMin = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[TimerMinKey] ?? "5";
            _logger.Info("Timer " + strMin);
            int.TryParse(strMin, out int minutos);

            int.TryParse(strMin, out minutos);

            _logger.Info("Set Timer Min " + strMin);
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60 * 1000 * minutos);
            _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Start(); // <- important
        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _logger.Info("Timer Elapse ");
            _timer.Enabled = false;
            _logger.Info("Timer Enabled = false ");
            //Cada tantos minutos configurados que pasen, se ejecuta el proceso
            ExecuteProcess();
        }

        internal void ExecuteProcess()
        {
            _logger.Info("Procesando Orders ");
            try
            {
                //Esta lista la tengo aqui fija, pero nose si se pueda cambiar y tomarse de uan BD o servicio.
                var listaEmails = new List<String>()
                {
                    "email@empresa.com",
                    "email2@empresa.com;otromeail@empresa.com",//Pueden ser varios separados por ;'
                    "email3@empresa.com",
                    "email3@empresa.com",
                    "email5@empresa.com",
                };

                //Procesar cada email
                foreach (var destinatario in listaEmails)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MailHelper mailHelper = new MailHelper(_logger);

                        var testMode = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SendTestModeKey] ?? "") == "1";
                        var testEmails = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SendTestEmailsKey];

                        var body = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[MailBodyKey];
                        var subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[MailSubjectKey];
                        var sender = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[MailAuthUserKey];

                        MailDataInfo mailData = new MailDataInfo();
                        mailData.Body = body;
                        mailData.Subject = subject;
                        var stringEmails = testMode ? testEmails : destinatario;// pueden ser varios emails separados por ;
                        var emails = stringEmails.Split(';');
                        mailData.Emails = new List<string>();
                        int count = 0;
                        foreach (var email in emails)
                        {
                            if (count == 0)
                            {
                                mailData.Recipient = email;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                mailData.Emails.Add(email);
                            }
                            count++;
                        }
                        //mailData.Recipient = sentRequest.Emails;
                        mailData.Sender = sender;
                        ///Si se quieres agregar algun archivo adjunto
                        //mailData.AttachmentFiles = new List<MailAttachmentFileInfo>();
                        //MailAttachmentFileInfo xmlFile = new MailAttachmentFileInfo
                        //{
                        //    FileName = "estearchivo.pdf",
                        //    FilePath = "c:/algo/estearchivo.pdf"
                        //};
                        //mailData.AttachmentFiles.Add(xmlFile);

                        var result = mailHelper.Send(mailData);
                        if (result.success)
                        {
                            _logger.Info("Email Enviado.");
                            _logger.Info(result.message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _logger.Info("Envio de email fallido.");
                            _logger.Warn(result.message);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _logger.Info("Error: " + e.Message, e);
                    }
                }

                if (_timer != null)
                {
                    _timer.Enabled = true;
                    _logger.Info("Timer Enabled = true ");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Info("Error: " + e.Message, e);
                if (_timer != null)
                {
                    _timer.Enabled = true;
                    _logger.Info("Timer Enabled = true ");
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _logger.Info("Servicio de prueba detenido. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Te explico las partes:

En **Declaraciones** o variables tenemos por una parte todos los keys (valores strings) que definen nombre de keys en nuestro `app.config`; tambien estan la varaible `_logger` que sirve para generar el log y el Timer cuyo objetivo principal sera repetir o ejecutar el proceso según el tiempo programado en `app.config`

El **constructor** que recibe como parámetro `ILog`.

El método **`OnStart`** que es donde inicializaremos el `Timer` asignándole el lapso de tiempo para cada ejecución.

El método **`timer_Elapse`** que solo se encarga de llamar ejecutar el proceso cada vez que pasen los minutos configurados en `app.config`.

Y por ultimo `ExecuteProcess()` que es donde irán todas las reglas de negocio del Servicio, en este ejemplo la función del código es enviar email, para eso agregue varias clases mas y genere algunas entidades, entre otras cosas.

4. Agregar los key al app.config

   ```
     <appSettings>
        <add key="Send.TestMode" value="1" />
        <add key="Send.TestEmails" value="destinatarioPrueba@gmail.com;destinatarioPrueba2@hotmail.com" />
        <add key="Timer.Min" value="3" />
        <add key="Mail.Subject" value="Servicio de correo de pruebas" />
        <add key="Mail.Body" value=" &lt;p&gt;Estimado(a) client(a): &lt;/p&gt; &lt;br&gt;&lt;p&gt;Correo de ejemplo de pruebas.&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;hr&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;ATENCIÓN:&lt;/b&gt;  Por favor, no responda a este mensaje, este buzón no es atendido." />
       <add key="Mail.Server" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
       <add key="Mail.Port" value="587" />
       <add key="Mail.Auth.User" value="noResponder@gmail.com" />
       <add key="Mail.Auth.Pass" value="********" />
       <add key="Mail.EnableSSL" value="1" />
     </appSettings>
   ```
5. Cambie el program.cs y quedo de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   using log4net;
   using System;
   using System.ServiceProcess;

   namespace ServicioDePrueba
   {
       internal class Program
        {
       //log para crear archivo de log y ver si algo esta fallando
       private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

       private static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Logger.Info("Programa iniciado: " + DateTime.Now);
    #if (!DEBUG)
           ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
           ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
           {
               new ServicioDePrueba(Logger)
           };
           ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    #else
           ServicioDePrueba myServ = new ServicioDePrueba(Logger);
           myServ.ExecuteProcess();
           // here Process is my Service function
           // that will run when my service onstart is call
           // you need to call your own method or function name here instead of Process();
    #endif
           Logger.Info("Programa Finalizado: " + DateTime.Now);
       }
   }
   }
   ```

De esta forma solo se encarga de correr el Servicio y ya no se comporta como una aplicación de consola.

**NOTA:** Los servicios no se pueden correr directamente, así que agregue un `#if (!DEBUG)` para que pueda correr en modo `Debug` creando una instancia del servicio directamente sin hacer la llamada `ServiceBase`, pero es importante al momento de generar la versión instalable aseguramos de tener `Release` seleccionado en las opciones del *Visual Studio*.

6. Agregar un Installer al servicio, para esto abrimos el servicio y damos clic derecho `Agregar instalador`.  Esto es necesario para poder correr el comando de instalación de Servicios de windows.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agregara un archivo `ProjectInstaller.cs`, le damos clic derecho y `Ver código`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServicioDePrueba
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Una vez allí damos clic derecho en `InitializeComponent()` y seleccionamos ir a definición, o F12.  En esta sección podemos agregar los datos de nuestro Servicio.

```
            // 
            // serviceInstaller1
            // 
            this.serviceInstaller1.Description = "Este solo es un servicio de prueba que envia emails.";
            this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = "ServicioDePrueba";
            this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "ServicioDePrueba";
```

Estos datos son los que veremos en los Servicios de Windows o en el `Task Manager`

7. Generar el Release.  Y copiar los archivos  la carpeta donde será instalado el Servicio, puede ser `c:\Servicios\Ejemplo`
8. Instalar el Servicio.  Para esto hay varias formas, puede ser desde `CMD` o desde `Developer Command Prompt`, yo lo hice con la segunda opción.

Hay que tomar varias cosas en cuenta; Primero correr `Developer Command Prompt` como administrador, y segunda cuando nos pida una cuenta de usuario poner `./userName` o `computerName/userName` de lo contrario nos marca un error y usar una cuenta local con contraseña.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

9. Iniciar el servicio.  Una vez instalado ya lo podremos visualizar en el `task manger` o en los servicios de windows, pero como detenido... así que hay que configurar el servicio para que inicie automático, seleccionar el usuario he iniciarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo de `LOG` será generado automáticamente al iniciar el servicio.

Lo puedes encontrar en la carpeta *Logs/ServicioDePrueba.log* y el nombre sera el que definimos en `app.config`, en la sección `Log4Net`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
2019-11-10 00:57:09,088 INFO [1] Program - Programa iniciado: 10/11/2019 12:57:09 a. m.
2019-11-10 00:57:09,100 INFO [1] Program - Procesando Orders 
2019-11-10 00:57:10,545 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:10,546 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:11,839 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:11,840 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:13,036 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:13,037 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:14,205 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:14,205 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:15,474 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:15,474 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:57:15,475 INFO [1] Program - Programa Finalizado: 10/11/2019 12:57:15 a. m.
2019-11-10 00:58:28,350 INFO [1] Program - Programa iniciado: 10/11/2019 12:58:28 a. m.
2019-11-10 00:58:28,359 INFO [1] Program - Procesando Orders 
2019-11-10 00:58:29,670 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:29,670 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:30,887 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:30,888 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:32,054 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:32,054 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:33,384 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:33,385 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:34,612 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:34,612 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:58:34,612 INFO [1] Program - Programa Finalizado: 10/11/2019 12:58:34 a. m.
2019-11-10 00:59:06,997 INFO [1] Program - Programa iniciado: 10/11/2019 12:59:06 a. m.
2019-11-10 00:59:07,005 INFO [1] Program - Procesando Orders 
2019-11-10 00:59:08,287 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:08,287 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:09,730 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:09,730 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:10,906 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:10,907 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:12,078 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:12,079 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:13,410 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:13,411 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:13,411 INFO [1] Program - Programa Finalizado: 10/11/2019 12:59:13 a. m.
2019-11-10 00:59:24,440 INFO [1] Program - Programa iniciado: 10/11/2019 12:59:24 a. m.
2019-11-10 00:59:24,450 INFO [1] Program - Procesando Orders 
2019-11-10 00:59:25,766 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:25,767 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:26,947 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:26,948 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:28,127 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:28,127 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:29,324 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:29,324 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:30,556 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:30,556 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 00:59:30,556 INFO [1] Program - Programa Finalizado: 10/11/2019 12:59:30 a. m.
2019-11-10 01:00:34,502 INFO [1] Program - Programa iniciado: 10/11/2019 01:00:34 a. m.
2019-11-10 01:00:34,510 INFO [1] Program - Procesando Orders 
2019-11-10 01:00:36,017 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:36,017 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:37,208 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:37,208 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:38,409 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:38,410 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:39,646 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:39,646 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:40,835 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:40,835 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:00:40,836 INFO [1] Program - Programa Finalizado: 10/11/2019 01:00:40 a. m.
2019-11-10 01:04:07,438 INFO [1] Program - Programa iniciado: 10/11/2019 01:04:07 a. m.
2019-11-10 01:04:07,445 INFO [1] Program - Procesando Orders 
2019-11-10 01:04:08,920 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:08,920 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:10,093 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:10,093 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:11,338 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:11,338 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:12,534 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:12,534 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:13,709 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:13,710 INFO [1] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:04:13,710 INFO [1] Program - Programa Finalizado: 10/11/2019 01:04:13 a. m.
2019-11-10 01:07:19,550 INFO [1] Program - Programa iniciado: 10/11/2019 01:07:19 a. m.
2019-11-10 01:07:19,557 INFO [4] Program - Servicio iniciado.
2019-11-10 01:07:19,558 INFO [4] Program - Timer 3
2019-11-10 01:07:19,558 INFO [4] Program - Set Timer Min 3
2019-11-10 01:10:19,560 INFO [5] Program - Timer Elapse 
2019-11-10 01:10:19,560 INFO [5] Program - Timer Enabled = false 
2019-11-10 01:10:19,563 INFO [5] Program - Procesando Orders 
2019-11-10 01:10:24,365 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:24,365 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:25,601 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:25,602 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:26,840 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:26,840 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:29,099 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:29,100 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:30,286 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:30,287 INFO [5] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:10:30,287 INFO [5] Program - Timer Enabled = true 
2019-11-10 01:13:30,298 INFO [8] Program - Timer Elapse 
2019-11-10 01:13:30,298 INFO [8] Program - Timer Enabled = false 
2019-11-10 01:13:30,298 INFO [8] Program - Procesando Orders 
2019-11-10 01:13:31,504 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:31,504 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:32,701 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:32,701 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:33,940 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:33,941 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:35,134 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:35,134 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:36,310 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:36,311 INFO [8] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:13:36,311 INFO [8] Program - Timer Enabled = true 
2019-11-10 01:16:36,324 INFO [9] Program - Timer Elapse 
2019-11-10 01:16:36,325 INFO [9] Program - Timer Enabled = false 
2019-11-10 01:16:36,325 INFO [9] Program - Procesando Orders 
2019-11-10 01:16:37,689 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:37,689 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:39,939 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:39,940 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:44,180 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:44,181 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:46,442 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:46,443 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:47,647 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:47,647 INFO [9] Program - Email Enviado.
2019-11-10 01:16:47,648 INFO [9] Program - Timer Enabled = true 
2019-11-10 01:17:27,052 INFO [10] Program - Servicio de prueba detenido. 
2019-11-10 01:17:27,053 INFO [1] Program - Programa Finalizado: 10/11/2019 01:17:27 a. m.
```

Si hay algún error se verá algo así en el archivo `.log`

```
2019-11-10 00:44:30,750 WARN [1] Program - Error al enviar email.
2019-11-10 00:44:31,198 ERROR [1] Program - El servidor SMTP requiere una conexión segura o el cliente no se autenticó. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: El servidor SMTP requiere una conexión segura o el cliente no se autenticó. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
   en System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   en System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   en ServicioDePrueba.Helper.MailHelper.Send(MailDataInfo mailData) en ServicioDePrueba\ServicioDePrueba\Helpers\MailHelper.cs:línea 104
2019-11-10 00:44:31,199 INFO [1] Program - Envio de email fallido.
2019-11-10 00:44:31,199 WARN [1] Program - Error al enviar email.
```

Para hacer funcionar el envió de `email` yo utilice `smtp` de **gmail**, por default gmail bloquea el envió de correo mediante aplicaciones, si es el caso, y si pretendes usar gmail hay que permitir aplicaciones da clic [aqui](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) para ir la configuración de gmail.

Espero poder ayudarte con esta respuesta y que sea de utilidad para mas miembros de la comunidad.  Cualquier duda me puedes contactar, Saludos.